# Stream.on() for follow event doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, twitter, bots

I am trying to listen to a follow event in this twitter bot but it doesn't work? Any idea?
Thank in advance

```
const stream = T.stream("statuses/filter", { track:"<twitteraccount>" }); 

function followed(event) {
  console.log("follow event");
  const name = event.source.name;
  const screenName = event.source.screen_name;
  tweeting(".@" + screenName + " hello you");
}

stream.on("follow", followed);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `follow` event in the filtered stream API. Where are you seeing this documented? In order to build something like this, you would need to use webhooks, and the Account Activity API.

Comment: oh, thanks, I was following an old tutorial then, using the twit library